# Disable all local Windows accounts

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to make a batch script that disable all local user accounts of a computer or a way to list all the users, one below another.

I try to generate a file with the command:

```
net user > %systemroot%\users.txt | findstr /I adm
```

but the command returns me all users in the same line.

If someone knows how to generate every user in a separate line, it helps me too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working code snippet:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%G in (
    'wmic USERACCOUNT where "Name!='Administrator'" get Name /value'
) do for /F "tokens=*" %%x in ("%%H") do (
    echo %%x
    rem some further command(s) here
)
```

Where the `for` loops are

- `%%G` to retrieve the `Name` value (in the second token, `%%H`);
- `%%x` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` instead of common `0x0D0A`), see the example below.

**Example** (copy & paste from my command line window):

```
==>for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %G in ('wmic USERACCOUNT where "Name!='Administra
tor'" get Name /value') do @echo "%H"
""
""
"Guest
""
""
"Edgar
""
""
"Allan
""
""
"Poe
""
""
""


==>for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %G in ('wmic USERACCOUNT where "Name!='Administra
tor'" get Name /value') do @for /F "tokens=*" %x in ("%H") do @echo "%x"
"Guest"
"Edgar"
"Allan"
"Poe"

==>
```

Comment: @Menusi and what about `wmic USERACCOUNT  get Name /value` just right from command line?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe net.exe can output them as separate lines, but you can use a `call` statement with `shift` to break the line into separate variables.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('net user ^| findstr /i adm') do set userlist=%%a
call :process %userlist%
goto :eof

:process
if {%1}=={} goto :eof

::-----------
rem Do something with %1 here
echo %1
::-----------

shift
goto :process
```

Comment: Can't work as `net user` returns all user accounts (three ones in a line) while `net user | findstr /i adm` returns only line containing `Administrator` plus two user accounts and **omits** any next user account.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that solved to me:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('net user ^| findstr -V "Contas de usu" ^| findstr -V "Comando conc" ^| findstr -V "\-" ^| findstr -V "User accounts" ^| findstr -V "The command"') do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      if not "%%b" == "Administrador" (
         if not "%%b" == "Administrator" (
            if not "%%b" == "Convidado" (                   
               Net user %%b /active:no
            ) else (
               for /f "delims=" %%c in ('ver ^| findstr /i "5\.1\."') do (
                  set version=%%c
               )
               if not {"!version!"} == {""} (
                  Net user "Convidado" /active:yes
               ) else (                      
                  Net user "Convidado" /active:no
               )

            )
         ) else (
            Net user "Administrator" /active:yes   
         )
      ) else (
         Net user "Administrador" /active:yes
      )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE localaccount=true set disabled=true
```

run it with **admin privileges**.